# Cocoapods and SVN

Tags: xcode, svn, repository, cocoapods

How can I use the pods files from a remote SVN server, a private server **protected by username and password**, after creating the complete structure needed for Cocoapods ?

thanks

**Update**

Move the all sources inside a sub-directory named with version of sources (eg trunk/2.0.0) and declare it on pod like below :

pod 'MyLibrary', :svn => 'http://svn-your-ip/svn/MyLibrary/trunk/2.0.0'

Answer (score 0):

The easiest variant would be to create a local checkout, and then [reference the path](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#pod) like so:

```
pod 'AFNetworking', :path => '~/Documents/AFNetworking'
```